# What is an analogous version of the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process on Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Recall that the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck (OU) process in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is defined by the following SDE,
$$
d Z_t=\frac{-1}{2} Z_t d t+d W_t, \quad t \geqslant 0
$$
where $\left(W_t\right)_{t \geqslant 0}$ is a standard $d$ dimensional Brownian motion. As it is well known, the process $Z$ admits the following explicit representation
$$
Z_t=Z_0 e^{-t / 2}+e^{-t / 2} \int_0^t e^{s / 2} d W_s, \quad t \geqslant 0.
$$
Furthermore, the infinitesimal generator of the above process is the following operator
$$L:=\Delta -x\cdot \nabla.$$

I was wondering what would be a generalization of this operator to Riemannian Manifolds? I know that Brownian motion can be constructed on manifolds and its generator is simply the Laplace Beltrami operator, however, the OU process has a drift and so I am not sure what is the appropriate way to generalize this to a sphere, for instance.

Comment: Just take the negative gradient field of the distance function with respect to a fixed reference point.

Comment: @RW thanks for your comment, but will that operator be the generator of the OU process on the manifold?

Comment: How do you define the OU process on a general manifold?

Comment: Are you familiar with Dirichlet forms?  That's how I would extend this, fix a smooth measure $\mu$ on $(M,g)$, and consider the Dirichlet form on $L^2(M, \mu)$ defined formally by $\mathcal{E}(f) = \int_M |\nabla f|^2\,d\mu$.  It induces a continuous Markov process $X_t$ symmetric with respect to $\mu$.  On $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mu$ being Gaussian measure, the resulting $X_t$ is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Comment: Also, if $\mu$ is the Riemannian volume measure, then the resulting $X_t$ is Brownian motion on $(M,g)$.  So Ornstein-Uhlenbeck and its generalizations are, in some sense, the Brownian motion for some "weighting" of $(M,g)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for your comments. This makes sense, so I guess then the issue is to figure out a natural version of the gaussian measure on a curved space. Perhaps measures of the form $\mu = e^{-f} d\text{vol}_g$ might be more appropriate?

Comment: @Student: I would say the natural analogue of the Gaussian is the heat kernel.  Note that by Radon-Nikodym, saying $\mu = e^{-f} d\mathrm{vol}$ is equivalent to saying "smooth measure" and just adding the condition "strictly positive density".  Any two such measures are mutually absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, there is a natural analogue whose Dirichlet form is in terms of a Gaussian kernel
eg. see sections 3,4 in "Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Type Processes on Wasserstein Space"

First they construct the generator and Dirichlet form $dG_{Q}$ (for covariance kernel $Q$) on the tangent space. And then we can use the exponential map sending $Exp: T_{x}\to M$ to precompose to create a Dirichlet form measure $dN_{Q}=dG_{Q}\circ Exp^{-1}$ on the manifold.

[image]

[image]